# Find bold text in a para using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to find all bold text  in a para and wrap them in italics. Which is the easiest way to do this?

I am using jQuery 1.6

Comment: also can I avoid using 'each'?

Comment: just finding an alternative without each

Comment: Any insight into why you want to wrap them rather than directly modifying the CSS?

Comment: I am not sure why you need javascript for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("strong").wrap("<em></em>")
```

Or use

```
$("b").wrap("<em></em>")
```

Comment: I want to keep the bold too. Just wrap the bold in italics, and not for one occurrence but multiple occurrences

Comment: $('strong,b', 'p').wrap('<em></em>');

Comment: It's not only for one occurrence. It will be applied to all bold elements. Just ignore the unwrap() method, and that will not remove the bold tag.

Answer (score 1):

Working example not using each:

http://jsfiddle.net/3KrQT/

Answer (score 0):

`$('b').each(function(){`
`$(this).html("<i>" + $(this).html() + "</i>");`
`});`

Not using .each
`<style>`
`.italics{`
`font-style:italic;`
`font-weight:bold;`
`}`
`</style>`

`$(document).ready(function(){`
`$('b').addClass('italics');`
`});`

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way i can think of would be to use css

```
$('strong, b').css('font-style','italic');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it:

```
$("b").wrap("<i/>");
```